# Sobre Pygame, eu preciso q uma imagem fique menor e logo dps volte ao seu tamanho normal, cm um botão sendo apertado por exemplo

Tags: python, funções, jogos, pygame, range

Meu principal problema é que quando eu crio uma função para fazer com que a imagem volte ao tamanho normal, em vez dela diminuir e voltar ao normal, ela simplesmente pula a etapa de diminuir a imagem.

(neste não tem a função de voltar ao normal)

```
if comando[pygame.K_SPACE]:   
            fm=[]
            for i in range(5):
                ll=random.randint(0,4)
                if ll==1:
                    vetorrosa.diminuir()
                    vetorrosa_group.update()
                    vetorrosa_group.draw(BACKGROUND)
                    fm.append(ll)
                    print('rosa')
                elif ll==2:
                    vetorazul.diminuir()
                    vetorazul_group.update()
                    vetorazul_group.draw(BACKGROUND)
                    fm.append(ll)
                    print('azul')
                elif ll==3:
                    vetormarinho.diminuir()
                    vetormarinho_group.update()
                    vetormarinho_group.draw(BACKGROUND)
                    fm.append(ll)
                    print('marinho')
                elif ll==4:
                    vetorvermelho.diminuir()
                    vetorvermelho_group.update()
                    vetorvermelho_group.draw(BACKGROUND)
                    fm.append(ll)
                    print('vermelho')
```

Por gentileza, gostaria de saber como posso resolver isso. Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Comment: se você não colocar umt recho de código que permita com que as pessoas possam reproduzir o que vocẽ está tentando, não é possível responder. Não preciamos ter todas as opçõs dos "elif" - mas é necessario cer o código da classe desse "vetormarinho" - e o método "diminuir" - se tiver uma função principal que tenha as etapas de desenhar a imagem na tela,e carregar a imagem do disco - melhor.

Comment: Dito tudo isso: não dá pra saber o que o seu método "diminuir" faz - mas você vai precisar guardar várias cópias da imagem na memória: 1 para cada tamanho que quiser mostrar  - e só mudar o atributo que é desenhado dentro do método "draw" (deve ser o atributo "image" de cada Sprite) - para fazer referência ao tamanho desejado.

Comment: S tivsse aí o codigo mínimo para desenar o que você quer na tela, seria bem tranquilo responder - do jeito que está, é impossível.